# Is $\mathbb{P}( X > Y) = \mathbb{P}( X+k > Y+k )$ true, where X and Y are random variables?

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

My intuition tells me that $\mathbb{P}(X+k > Y+k) = \mathbb{P}(X > Y)$ should be true, since there (should?) be a bijection between every single result between these two probability distributions. But clearly there's a misunderstanding somewhere here, but I'm having trouble pinning it down.

A counterexample would be:
Suppose $X \sim \operatorname{Bin}(n, 0.5)$ and $Y \sim \operatorname{Bin}(n+1, 0.5)$.
$\mathbb{P}(X < Y) = \mathbb{P}(n-X < n+1-Y)$, since the probability distribution of $\operatorname{Bin}(n, 0.5)$ and $n - X$ should be exactly the same.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: How is your counterexample a counterexample?

Comment: I just realized this - but the signs have swapped in my "counterexample". Is this where the source of confusion is? In that case is P(X>Y) = P(X+k > Y+k) true?

Comment: I don't see what your example has to do with $P(X+k>Y+k)=P(X>Y)$, which is a true statement. (In fact the two events themselves are identical.)

Comment: Yes it's true :)

Comment: They are so equal that one would use the equality without comment, just as one would use without comment the fact that $U\gt V$ if and only if $U-V\gt 0$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $\mathbb{P}(X>Y)=\mathbb{P}(\lbrace\omega\in \Omega:X(\omega)>Y(\omega)\rbrace)$, but $X(\omega),Y(\omega)$ are real numbers, then $X(\omega)>Y(\omega)$ if and only if $X(\omega)+k>Y(\omega)+k$.

Comment: Why hint? Being humble? :P